# Assembly publisher specification

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Please, tell me how can I specify publisher of assembly (class library). I specify Company name in project properties but Publisher property of final dll stay empty.

Comment: Is this is a Microsoft Office Add-In?

Comment: Not is simple class library which i use as simple dll file in another application

Answer (score 1):

I think the publisher attribute you are talking about is applicable only for media file